# How would I normalize dates in a csv file? python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a CSV file with a field named  `start_date` that contains data in a variety of formats.

Some of the formats include e.g., `June 23, 1912` or `5/11/1930` (month, day, year). But not all values are valid dates.

I want to add a `start_date_description` field adjacent to the `start_date` column to filter invalid date values into. Lastly, normalize all valid date values in start_date to ISO 8601 (i.e., `YYYY-MM-DD`).

So far I was only able to load the start_date into my file, I am stuck and would appreciate ant help. Please, any solution especially without using a library would be great!

```
import csv

date_column = ("start_date")
f = open("test.csv","r")
csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

headers = None
results = []
for row in csv_reader:
    if not headers:
        headers = []
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
           if col in date_column:
            headers.append(i)
    else:
        results.append(([row[i] for i in headers]))

print results
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the [`dateparser` module](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could help here if you don't know the exact formats of the dates you're receiving

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `dateutil` module, you can parse data as follows:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse('3/16/78')
parser.parse('4-Apr') # this will give current year i.e. 2017
```

Then parsing to your format can be done by

```
dt = parser.parse('3/16/78')
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Suppose you have table in dataframe format, you can now define parsing function and apply to column as follows:

```
def parse_date(start_time):
    try:
        return parser.parse(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except:
        return ''
df['parse_date'] = df.start_date.map(lambda x: parse_date(x))
```

Comment: How would run your example to be evaluated by the whole csv file?

Comment: I update the my solution. Let me know if it works for you. I assume that your dataframe has `start_date` as a column

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: ... add a start_date_description ... normalize ... to ISO 8601

This reads the File `test.csv` and validates the Date String in Column `start_date` with Date Directive Patterns and returns a 
`dict{description, ISO}`.  The returned `dict` is used to update the current Row `dict` and the updated Row `dict` is writen to the File `test_update.csv`.

**Put this in a NEW Python File and run it!**

A missing valid Date Directive Pattern could be simple added to the Array.

> Python » 3.6 Documentation: [8.1.8. strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import re

def validate(date):
    def _dict(desc, date):
        return {'start_date_description':desc, 'ISO':date}

    for format in [('%m/%d/%y','Valid'), ('%b-%y','Short, missing Day'), ('%d-%b-%y','Valid'),
                   ('%d-%b','Short, missing Year')]: #, ('%B %d. %Y','Valid')]:
        try:
            _dt = dt.strptime(date, format[0])
            return _dict(format[1], _dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        except:
            continue

    if not re.search(r'\d+', date):
        return _dict('No Digit', None)

    return _dict('Unknown Pattern', None)

with open('test.csv') as fh_in, open('test_update.csv', 'w') as fh_out:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fh_in)
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(fh_out,
                                fieldnames=csv_reader.fieldnames +
                                           ['start_date_description', 'ISO'] )
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for row, values in enumerate(csv_reader,2):
        values.update(validate(values['start_date']))

        # Show only Invalid Dates
        if any(w in values['start_date_description'] 
               for w in ['Unknown', 'No Digit', 'missing']):

            print('{:>3}: {v[start_date]:13.13} {v[start_date_description]:<22} {v[ISO]}'.
                  format(row, v=values))

        csv_writer.writerow(values)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> start_date    start_date_description ISO
> June 23. 1912 Valid                  1912-06-23
> 12/31/91      Valid                  1991-12-31
> Oct-84        Short, missing Day     1984-10-01
> Feb-09        Short, missing Day     2009-02-01
> 10-Dec-80     Valid                  1980-12-10
> 10/7/81       Valid                  1981-10-07
> Facere volupt No Digit               None
> ... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I ran your code and it didn't work, it continues to say "_data" is not defined. I placed your code directly below mines, then ran it. Any suggestions?

Comment: The file name is on the image I uploaded, should i change _data to the file name ?

Comment: I ran it again and only what you placed in sDate was printed to the console, the actual file wasn't evaluated.